# Reconstructing a gam model fit in R, in Python

Tags: r, python, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I am currently building a gam model in R. However, I need to deploy the model in Python. So I was wondering if it is possible like in linear regression if we could just recreate the equation using the variables and coefficients while deploying. Any links on understanding the gam parameters are very appreciated. Please note that I am not looking for an implementation of GAM in python. I want the training to be in R and the deployment to be in Python.

Comment: You can call R within Python. can’t you?